# Espresso Test DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am writing my first espresso test for an Android app, a simple calculator. The user inputs a value in Editbox1(id: input) and another in EditBox2(id: input1) and then clicks on a button with an operator, lets say '+'. The result is displayed in a result textview. My EditTexts are set to input type numberDecimal and are stored as a Double. The result is also a Double which is sent to the result TextView.

But when I run this test, I get following error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "30"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "30"
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131427424, res-name=result, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=218, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=166.0, text=30.0, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.varun.calculator_prac.ExampleInstrumentedTest.testAddition(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:63)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'with text: is "30"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "30"
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131427424, res-name=result, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=218, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=166.0, text=30.0, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:1053)
at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$2.check(ViewAssertions.java:89)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Tests ran to completion.
```

My Test code is:

```
package com.varun.calculator_prac;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Instrumentation test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> CalcActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, true);

    @Before
    public void init(){
        UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        try {
            if (!uiDevice.isScreenOn()) {
                uiDevice.wakeUp();
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.varun.calculator_prac", appContext.getPackageName());

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddition(){
        onView(withId(R.id.input)).perform(typeText("5"),closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.input1)).perform(typeText("25"),closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.sum)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.result)).check(matches(withText(("30"))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you change your test as below and check:

```
@Test
    public void testAddition(){
        onView(withId(R.id.input)).perform(typeText("5.0"),closeSoftKeyboard());
        onView(withId(R.id.input1)).perform(typeText("25.0"),closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.sum)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.result)).check(matches(withText(("30.0"))));
    }
```

Comment: Oh god. So simple! I'm embarrassed that I messed up like this. Thank you!